# Can a minor be "self-employed?"

Tags: united-states, business, minor

I would like to sell web design services, but I don't know where to begin with the legal details. Is there anything that I have to look out for? Do I have to pay taxes? I am 17 years old.

Comment: "Legal details" is the least of your worry. Make sure you have customers. Make sure money flows. Then hire an accountant/lawyer to straighten legal stuff out for you, by which time you'd probably no longer be a minor anymore.

Comment: @Greendrake It seems to me that it is rather more responsible to have some understanding of the legal details *before* looking for customers rather than the other way around.  Someone who solicits business without understanding the legal details, and therefore the costs of doing business, might make promises that are impossible to keep without losing money.  Similarly, getting an accountant *after* money starts to flow seems fraught with peril.

Comment: Moreover, the running of a small business is off-topic here, while any legalities pertaining to a minor running a business are on topic.